# JavaScript, Using a for loop to calculate the sum of all the values within an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I just starting using JavaScript a couple weeks ago and still struggling a bit. I need to create a loop that calculates the sum of all values coming from a votes array in a separate .js file.

The function has a single parameter, votes, representing one of the five vote arrays (vote1 through vote5). Add the following commands to the function:

a. Declare a variable named total, setting its initial value to 0.

b. Create a for loop that loops through each of the items in the votes array, adding that item’s value to the total variable.

c. After the for loop is completed, return the value of the total variable from the function.

Heres my html file.

```
<script>
    function totalVotes()
    {
        var total = 0;

        for (i=0; i < votes.length; ++i)
            {
                total += votes[i];
            }
            return total;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You will want to learn about objects and properties, to use them as a structure instead of those many variables. Also, array and object literals.

Comment: ...and learn about [function parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Comment: Your loop is fine. All your code is missing is the declaration of `votes` as a parameter of the function, and the actual call (e.g. `totalVotes(votes3)`).

Comment: Be careful about asking StackOverflow for your homework questions. If you post something directly from here you will almost certainly be "asked" about it by a teacher.

Your code in the HTML is almost correct for calculating totals, you should say `var i = 0` or `let i = 0` instead of `i=0`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use **reduce** Method of array. **Reduce Method** gives concatenated value based on elements across the Array. For Example :

```
const sum = [1,2,3].reduce(function(result,item) {
 return result + item;
}, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

The above code gives the output 6 that is the sum of given array.
You can check other methods of array on my Gist: [Iterate_Over_Array.js](https://gist.github.com/NishiGaba/c0b1416ab6215f2592034cc66aaf0d86)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to pass in the array you want to iterate over:

```js
var vote1 = [45125, 44498, 5143]

function totalVotes(votes) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < votes.length; i++) {
    total += votes[i];
  }
  return total;
}

// better alternative
function tallyVotes(votes) {
  return votes.reduce((total, vote) => total + vote, 0);
}

console.log('for loop: ', totalVotes(vote1));
console.log('reduce: ', tallyVotes(vote1));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to create Javascript Object instead of array of different properties.If you use Object then you will have to create Array of Objects with following structure -

```
var first_object = {
     'name':"Jeffrey Hart",
     'party':"D",
     'race':"1st Congressional District",
     'vote':"45125"
}
```

You will create object for each record and use Arrays.push to add into your array. Lets assume array is records, then use

`records.push(first_object)`

After Adding all the records then you will have arrays of Objects now you can tracer through it with simple forEach loop

```
var total = 0;
records.forEach( function (record)
{
    total+= record.vote;
});
```

If you are new to Javascript I would recommend to read

> JavaScript: The Good Parts By Douglas Crockford

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do

Answer (score 1):

You can add the numbers like below

```
let total = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < this.state.seatArray.length; i++) {
    total += total + parseInt(this.state.seatArray[i].price);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add the numbers like below

```
for(let i = 0; i < product.length; i++)
 {
   var count1=+product[i].Pending;
   var count2=+product[i].Competed;
   this.totalCount=this.totalCount+(+count1)+(+count2);
}
```

Declare `totalCount` globally on top `totalCount:number=0;`.